# Extract POSIXct information from large vector

Tags: r, vector, subset, posixct

I have a large POSIXct vector `v2` with 438000 elements, created as follows:

```
t.start <- as.POSIXct("2016-08-16 15:00:00 CEST")
v1 <- seq(from = t.start, length.out = 2920, by = "3 hours")
v2 <- rep(v1, each = 150)
```

From `v2`, I would like to extract the 12 elements that - for the first time they appear - contain the first day of each month. Specifically, I look for:

1. The numeric position in `v2` these 12 elements have
2. The actual date of these elements in `%d %b` format, e.g. "01 Sep"

These two things should be extracted separately, i.e. stored in two different vectors afterwards. I think `v1` and `v2` contain daylight saving POSIXct elements but that should not affect the general operation. Any hint on how I can bypass the daylight savings would be a nice little add-on!

Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: Are you allowed to use a package like lubridate? It would help to visualize what you want if you would show  the output you are looking for or at least the first few lines.

Comment: I don't know if I get you - yes, I am allowed to use lubridate though I've not worked with it yet. With the output, well, that's what I am looking for. The second output vector would look like this: `lbl_v2("01 Sep", "01 Oct", "01 Nov", [...], "01 Aug")`. For each of these 12 elements, I am also looking for the position they are stored in `v2`. This should be a numeric vector containing the respective element number the dates from `lbl_v2` appear in `v2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can start by extracting the day number from each element with `format(v2, "%d)`.  Then, to determine where the first days of the month are we can equate that to `"01"`. Then we can take the `diff()` of that logical vector, remembering to concatenate `0L` out front to account for the missing first element.  Wrap that in `which()`, and you have the indices of the first element of each first day.

```
w <- which(c(0L, diff(format(v2, "%d") == "01")) == 1L)
w
# [1]  18451  54451  91651 127801 165001 202201 235801 272851
# [9] 308851 346051 382051 419251
```

Now `w` holds the locations of the 12 elements we need.  Let's take a look at those elements of `v2`, just to confirm we've got it right.

```
v2[w]
#  [1] "2016-09-01 00:00:00 PDT" "2016-10-01 00:00:00 PDT"
#  [3] "2016-11-01 00:00:00 PDT" "2016-12-01 02:00:00 PST"
#  [5] "2017-01-01 02:00:00 PST" "2017-02-01 02:00:00 PST"
#  [7] "2017-03-01 02:00:00 PST" "2017-04-01 00:00:00 PDT"
#  [9] "2017-05-01 00:00:00 PDT" "2017-06-01 00:00:00 PDT"
# [11] "2017-07-01 00:00:00 PDT" "2017-08-01 00:00:00 PDT"
```

Looks good.  Note that we've got some 2am entries there, which is fine because it's Daylight Savings Time.  Now let's get to your desired format ...

```
format(v2[w], "%d %b")
# [1] "01 Sep" "01 Oct" "01 Nov" "01 Dec" "01 Jan" "01 Feb"
# [7] "01 Mar" "01 Apr" "01 May" "01 Jun" "01 Jul" "01 Aug"
```